# Windows 8 next to Xubuntu

Tags: windows, xubuntu, disk-usage

Aye,

I have already installed latest Xubuntu and it takes my whole disk. I want to install Windows 8 now next to it. Can I make Xubuntu partionion smaller to make space for Windows? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boot from the LiveCD/USB that you used to install Xubuntu. When fully booted, run `Gparted` software that is included. With it, you can resize partitions by simply dragging borders. Never try to resize the partition that is mounted or booted from.

Comment: Ok, that worked for me. So when ill install Windows 7 (decided it will be 7 not 8) on this unlocated disk part, wont then Windows GRUB override Xubuntu GRUB and I will not have access to Xubuntu? How to make this work properly

Comment: It will. You will have to fix with your LiveUSB again. There is at least 10 000 articles on this topic over Internet.